# How to access Outlook365 shared mailbox with Perl Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: perl, exchange-server, imap

I'm using Perl Mail::IMAPClient to connect to an Outlook365 account that also has access to a shared mailbox by using the following code:

```
# We create the socket connection to the server.
my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(  
   PeerAddr => 'outlook.office365.com',  
   PeerPort => 993,
   SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE
)  
or die "socket(): $@";  

# We connect to the IMAP server.
$client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    User => $username,
    Password => $password,  
    SSL => 1,
   Socket => $socket
) || die "I cannot create Mail::IMAPClient object: $@";

$client->State(Mail::IMAPClient::Connected);

my @folders = $client->folders();
```

However, the `@folders` array contains only the folders from my user account but not those in the shared mailbox.

How can I access the shared mailbox folders?

Comment: You have mixed `or die` and `|| die`. The second one is not entirely correct as it has a higher associativity. In this specific case that doesn't matter, but it's bad style. For the `or die` always use `or`.

Comment: Can you access those shared folders with an email client like Thunderbird via IMAP? Having dealt with the Exchange API recently, I suspect that those are not available via IMAP at all because they are not part of your mailbox.